# Passing parent div to popup div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, outerhtml

I'm designing a page for a client and I have a database table inside a div called 'areaToPrint' that I want to print in some way, and I want to be able to css format the table. The basic idea is to use javascript to send the 'areaToPrint'.innerhtml to a div called 'printer' inside my css formated file printer.php.

//My script in the main/parent page

```
<script>
function printDiv()
{
var divToPrint=document.getElementById('areaToPrint');
var newWin = window.open("printer.php");
newWin.document.getElementById('printer').innerHTML=divToPrint.innerHTML;
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
}
</script>
```

//body element inside Printer.php

```
<body>
<div id="printer"></div>
</body>
```

I want the content of areaToPrint to fill the printer div in the popuped printer.php. 
I was able to do a similar task using something like

```
newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML)
```

But i want to be able to css format the table inside the div. 
(The javascript is called with a link)

Any suggestions on javascript faulties?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe jQuery would be helpful with

```
$(this).parent()
$("someone").css()
$("someone").addClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to dynamically format the table with JavaScript  (  e.g. change visual styles based on interaction), the easiest way would be to include a stylesheet in your printer.php view template.

e.g.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="text/css" media="print" href="css/print.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="printer"></div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Yes, that's how i do it in my printer. I just didn't include the head block. My problem is how to do the Javascript and to address the printer div.

Comment: In that case I'm not exactly sure what it is your asking for, you question says you want to know how to add CSS styling to it. Can you clarify please.

Comment: i'm sorry if i made myself unclear. I want to take the content of a div on my main page, open up a new window printer.php and fill its printer div with that content! I can do a outerHTML write, but then I lose my css format.

Comment: you can't take the formatting with the content ( not via any simple means anyway ). Like I said the easiest way is to include a stylesheet in your popup window, to style the content. When you insert the content it will then get styled by the stylesheet.

Comment: thanks for trying. but your still not getting my point. I know I can include a css file in the head block, but I didn't include the head block in the code above, since that is off topic. My problem is still the javascript and how to get it inside the printer DIV

Comment: Sorry, in that case I really don't understand what it is your asking for. Can you clarify what you mean by this `But i want to be able to css format the table inside the div. (The javascript is called with a link)`